# Intuition behind minimizing the Dirichlet energy of a mapping

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, computational-geometry

What does minimizing the Dirichlet energy of a mapping $\Phi$ achieve intuitively?
Roughly it is the integral (or sum, if discrete) of $|\nabla \Phi(\;)|^2 dV$, with $V$ the volume.
So is it, in some sense, a minimally distorting (on average) mapping?
Here is an example,

[image: Figure 5]

from

> Yaron Lipman.
>   "Construction of Injective Mappings Of Meshes."
>   [arXiv:1310.0955 [cs.CG]](http://arxiv-web3.library.cornell.edu/abs/1310.0955).

But when I look at this figure and try to view it as minimally distorting, I don't see 
in what sense it minimally distorts—it greatly distorts!
I feel like I am missing some basic intuition here.
Any insights would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but the boundary is fixed, probably pointwise, as that of (b), and the minimizer squeezes most of it into a dark mush in the middle, and stretches near the boundary, where it has little choice. I can't seem to find the title of Courant's book on variational methods, you would enjoy browsing that. This can be downloaded: http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1943-49-01/S0002-9904-1943-07818-4/

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Dirichlets-Principle-Conformal-Surfaces-Mathematics/dp/0486445526

Comment: Thanks, Will. Perhaps there is little more to say beyond your explanation.